# Controlling vertical space within a cases environment

Tags: spacing, cases, vertical

I'm trying to define a function that requires a large amount of text in a cases environment. By adding a

```
\\
```

I can create some space between the top and bottom lines, but i'd rather create a smaller space (perhaps half a line), \smallskip and similar don't seem to work in this environment, and adding extra options to

```
\\
```

like [5pt] also seems not to work.

Any ideas what will?

```
p_k(j,M)&=
\begin{cases}
1\text{ } \parbox[t]{.6\textwidth}{ if the matrix $M$ includes one or more entry of the value $k$ in the row $j$ of $M$,}\\
\\
0 \text{ otherwise.} 
\end{cases}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you miss the `&`s in the right position.

I think `[5pt]` are too few, try something greater, e.g. `[14pt]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[p_k(j,M)=
\begin{cases}
1 &\parbox[t]{.6\textwidth}{if the matrix $M$ includes one or more entry of the value $k$ in the row $j$ of $M$,}\\[14pt]
0 &\text{otherwise.} 
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Weirdly in my document, that piece of code produces even spacing between the lines. I assume this is to do with my headers, any idea what could cause this?

Comment: working on it ...

Comment: It appears to be due to \doublespacing I can only use 20pt or higher.

Comment: @Abijah Did you load `setspace`?

Comment: Yes I did :) :)

Comment: Try putting `\singlespacing` before the `\[` and againg `\doublespacing` after the `\]`